# Is the output of a variational autoencoder meant to be a distribution that can be sampled, or a sample directly?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, variational-bayes

It is difficult to ask this question succinctly in the title, so let me explain.

From all the examples of VAEs I have seen, there seem to be 2 approaches used to implement them.

1. In [these](https://jaan.io/what-is-variational-autoencoder-vae-tutorial/),  [approaches](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/variational-autoencoders/), the output of the decoder is a
   distribution. Specifically, a Bernoulli distribution. The loss is
   related to the likelihood of the input data with respect to this
   distribution. When generating new variables, not only are samples
   drawn from the latent space distributions, but also, samples are
   drawn from the output distributions. I have a question related to
   the parameterization of the output distributions using this
   approach, but I will save that for the end.
2. In [these](http://kvfrans.com/variational-autoencoders-explained/),  [approaches](https://towardsdatascience.com/teaching-a-variational-autoencoder-vae-to-draw-mnist-characters-978675c95776), the output of the decoder is the
       actual predicted data points, which are then compared to the input
       to calculate the loss, as mean squared error. The only thing that
       ever gets sampled is the latent space.

These 2 approaches are fundamentally different. I notice that in the first approach, the authors relate the idea to a statistical/probabilistic motivation, and it seems to have a solid theoretical foundation. For this reason I am inclined to adopt the 1st approach.

So my questions are:

1. Are either of these approaches considered to be superior?
2. The second question is more of a sense check: Bernoulli distribution
   makes sense for grey scale pixels. But for something like stock
   returns, we would want some other distribution, such as a
   t-distribution. In this case, the output of the encoder would be 3
   vectors, 1 for location, 1 for scale, and 1 for degrees of freedom,
   right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Question 1:**

The output of the decoder aims to model the distribution $p(x|t)$, i.e. the distribution of data $x$ given the latent variable $t$. Therefore, in principle, it **should always be probabilistic**.

**However,** in some cases, people simply use the mean squared error as the loss and, as you said, the output of the decoder is *the actual predicted data points*. Note that this approach can also be viewed as probabilistic, in the sense that it is is equivalent to modeling $p(x|t)$ as Gaussian with identity covariance, $p(x|t) = \mathcal{N}(x|\mu(t), I)$. In this case, the output of the decoder is the mean $\mu(t)$ and, therefore, for an example $x_i$, you get the following reconstruction loss:

\begin{align}
-\log(p(x_i | t_i)) &= -\log \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k |I|}} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu(t_i))^\intercal I (x_i-\mu(t_i))\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}||x_i - \mu(t_i)||^2 + \text{const.}
\end{align}

which, as you can see, is proportional to the mean squared error (plus some constant).

**Question 2:**

> Bernoulli distribution makes sense for grey scale pixels.

This is not quite true. The correct statement would be that **Bernoulli distribution makes sense for black and white (i.e. binary) images**. The Bernoulli distribution is binary, so it assumes that observations may only have two possible outcomes. It is true that people sometimes use it for grayscale images, but this is an abusive interpretation of the VAE. It may work pretty well for datasets that are *almost* black and white, like MNIST. However, a binarized version of the MNIST dataset exists and, in rigor, this is the version that should be used together with a Bernoulli VAE.

> But for something like stock returns, we would want some other distribution, such as a t-distribution. In this case, the output of the encoder would be 3 vectors, 1 for location, 1 for scale, and 1 for degrees of freedom, right?

I would try a Gaussian first, $p(x|t) = \mathcal{N}(x|\mu(t), \sigma^2(t))$, so the decoder would output two values, $\mu(t)$ and $\sigma^2(t)$. But yeah, if you really want a t-distribution, then that is the way to go.

Comment: Could you please explain why Bernoulli distribution makes sense only for black and white images? I understand what Bernoulli distribution does, but we are choosing a distribution for the latent space, not for the data samples space (which is binary), so I don’t find it quite evident why it makes sense to select this distribution for the latent space. Also, I have seen in some papers (e.g. $\beta$-VAE) that Bernoulli distribution is used for non-binary datasets.

Comment: I meant that a Bernoulli posterior $p(x|t)$ makes sense for black and white images, i.e. those where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. I was not talking about the posterior distribution on the latent space $p(t|x)$, which I was assuming to be Gaussian (as in "vanilla VAE"), but this need not be the case.

Comment: In the second case, N(x|mu, sigma^2), the expression for -log(p(x|t)) would include the terms 1/sigma^2 * ||x - mu||^2 + log(sigma). So the loss function would change. But what I don't understand is, how to output sigma from the decoder? Is it similar to how encoder outputs mu_z, sigma_z ? or there is some other technique?

Comment: You could that, but, in that case, the optimization problem is ill-posed (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373858/is-the-optimization-of-the-gaussian-vae-well-posed). Alternatively, you can simply set the variance to a fixed value, as a hyperparameter.

Comment: [This NeurIPS '19 paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/f82798ec8909d23e55679ee26bb26437-Paper.pdf) is all about the Bernoulli black/white/grayscale thing and proposes a simple solution: using a ContinuousBernoulli output distribution, which has proper support in [0, 1] (and not just in {0,1} like Bernoulli).