# How can be decoder of VAE represent probability distribution p(x|z) eventhough we directly get image as output

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models

How can be decoder of VAE represent probability distribution p(x|z) eventhough we directly get image as output. Also if my current understanding is right than we get same image for same value of z sampled by at bottleneck of VAE than how is decoder probabilistic.

Answer (score 1):

The decoder represents a multidimensional probability distribution.

If your "reconstruction loss" (the negative log-likelihood term) is the mean squared error, or variants thereafter, the decoder represents a multivariate Gaussian distribution.
This form implies a constant diagonal covariance (which is not usually estimated, and is assumed to be the same for every sample).
Then, the 'output' is the mean of such a distribution (which completely parametrizes a multivariate Gaussian with assumed known covariance)

If you optimize instead for "cross-entropy loss" (the Bernoulli negative loglikelihood), then the decoder represents a Bernoulli distribution.
In this case, the 'output' is the probability of a single trial (i.e., being 1 instead of 0).

---

Theoretically, you could sample from the decoder (see [Is the output of a variational autoencoder meant to be a distribution that can be sampled, or a sample directly?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/368001/60613)), since it is a conditional distribution.